# MenuContribution to Editor toolbar?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In my recent project, i contributed various commands to viewpart toolbars:

Example:
[alt text http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/toolbarexamplepunesgox.png](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/toolbarexamplepunesgox.png)
I want to do this for editors also. Is this possible and if it is, could some please point me in the right direction, on how this can be achieved?

Thanks! :-)
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editors don't have their own toolbar, like views do. They can only contribute to the "Main Toolbar", as seen here:

[image: Eclipse layout]

See [example 5](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html#example5), [example 6](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html#example6) and [example 8](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html#example8) in [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html).